# Android app cannot connect web server?

Tags: android

**Code**

```
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";

String URL_SERVER = "http://localhost/italk/servlet/login.ValidateUser";
//String URL_SERVER = "http://localhost/italk/servlet/login.ValidateUser";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    inputUserName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtUserName);
    inputPassWord = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPassWord);

    btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //Neu login ->true
            new doLogin().execute();
        }   
    });
}

class doLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
    * Getting product details in background thread
    * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        // updating UI from Background Thread
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            // Check for success tag
            String success;
            try {
                // Building Parameters
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user_name", inputUserName.getText().toString()));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pass_word", inputPassWord.getText().toString()));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("db_name", "jdbc/ITTALKDS"));
                // getting product details by making HTTP request
                // Note that product details url will use GET request
                JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                URL_SERVER, "GET", params);

                // check your log for json response
                //Log.d("Single Product Details", json.toString());

                // json success tag
                success = json.getString("result");
                if (success.equals("2")) {//Login successfully
                    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
                    pDialog.setMessage("Login successfully...");
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlliTalk.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                } else {
                    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
                    pDialog.setMessage("Login failt...");
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

        return null;
    }
}
```

**error message:**

```
06-24 23:17:01.946: E/AndroidRuntime(7968): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-24 23:17:01.946: E/AndroidRuntime(7968): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
06-24 23:17:01.946: E/AndroidRuntime(7968):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1117)
06-24 23:17:01.946: E/AndroidRuntime(7968):     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:84)
06-24 23:17:01.946: E/AndroidRuntime(7968):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
06-24 23:17:01.946: E/AndroidRuntime(7968):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
06-24 23:17:01.946: E/AndroidRuntime(7968):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
06-24 23:17:01.946: E/AndroidRuntime(7968):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
06-24 23:17:01.946: E/AndroidRuntime(7968):     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:842)
06-24 23:17:01.946: E/AndroidRuntime(7968):     at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:119)
06-24 23:17:01.946: E/AndroidRuntime(7968):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:144)
06-24 23:17:01.946: E/AndroidRuntime(7968):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
06-24 23:17:01.946: E/AndroidRuntime(7968):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
06-24 23:17:01.946: E/AndroidRuntime(7968):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
06-24 23:17:01.946: E/AndroidRuntime(7968):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
06-24 23:17:01.946: E/AndroidRuntime(7968):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
06-24 23:17:01.946: E/AndroidRuntime(7968):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
06-24 23:17:01.946: E/AndroidRuntime(7968):     at com.italk.JSONParser.makeHttpRequest(JSONParser.java:64)
06-24 23:17:01.946: E/AndroidRuntime(7968):     at com.italk.MainActivity$doLogin$1.run(MainActivity.java:74)
06-24 23:17:01.946: E/AndroidRuntime(7968):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
06-24 23:17:01.946: E/AndroidRuntime(7968):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-24 23:17:01.946: E/AndroidRuntime(7968):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-24 23:17:01.946: E/AndroidRuntime(7968):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
06-24 23:17:01.946: E/AndroidRuntime(7968):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-24 23:17:01.946: E/AndroidRuntime(7968):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-24 23:17:01.946: E/AndroidRuntime(7968):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
06-24 23:17:01.946: E/AndroidRuntime(7968):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
06-24 23:17:01.946: E/AndroidRuntime(7968):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: That's because you cannot use network services on main thread. Use `AsyncTask` to accomplish this...

Answer (score 1):

You cannot make network call on UI thread. Move your `runOnUiThread()` function to where you want to make a UI Thread operation.

Answer (score 0):

This question has been made on SO quite several times and has been solved every time.

Look at the article [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

EDIT :
I didn't see your code at first. You should not make httprequests in the `runOnUIThread`. The stacktrace states "Network on main thread". Which means you should do the network part in `AsyncTask`'s `doInBackground()` method, and update UI from main thread. Try getting the values at the `AsyncTask` and returning it to the main thread then update UI. Look at the article linked before for a clear idea.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `runOnUIThread()` and directly make the request in `doInBackground()`. Any code in `doInBackground()` is run on a separate thread so you don't need a runnable there.

Answer (score 0):

just remove the `runOnUiThread` inside the background thread. Because doInBanckground already run with separate thread to do the process in background

Comment: runOnUiThread is needed as parts of that code interact with the UI.  What needs to be done is to use it *only* for those parts, and not for the whole thing including the network code.